# Setting message post submit

Tags: jquery, messaging, form-submit, page-refresh

**Can anyone suggest a means to retain information via jquery post submit and page refresh?**

I have a customized search filter which works well but I need a system to inform the user of the search parameters the results are based on.

So effectively, when the user hits submit and the page refreshes, I need to retain information from their search input I can then display back to them as a reminder.

You can see my efforts at work here (http://www.plotsandhouses.com/node/29).**Only the price ranges produce the reminder message . so only provide input for the drop downlists and then submit**
You will see the update message at the top of the page.

I am currently trying the JQuery Cookie plugin project but it is sticky and the update message does not refresh quickly enough. So I get the a message from before my most recent.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use a GET instead of POST to send the user's values to the server, I'd hijack the default html POST form submit by using jquery to attach a click handler to the submit button, and in that click handler, read your form values, append them to some URL var, and then  call this to actually perform the redirect:

```
window.location = the_constructed_url;
```